# Omitting key:value items from a string

Tags: php, regex

How do I completely omit/delete key:value items from a string?

`(\w+):"?\K((?(?<=")[^"]*|\w*))`

I have this regex which seeks to find all key:value or key:"value" items. How do I remove these items completely from a string though?

`I like to ride a camel tag:videos tag:nope country:"none"` = `I like to ride a camel`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace("@[^\s]+\:[^\s]+\ @",'',"I like to ride a camel tag:videos tag:nope ");
```

I won't describe what the parameters of the `preg_replace()` method are, because it's all here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

`[^\s]` can be any character which is not a white space (it's anything but because of the `^`). The `+` behind it, means that this character can occur 1 time or more.

> \s stands for "whitespace character". Again, which characters this
>   actually includes, depends on the regex flavor. In all flavors
>   discussed in this tutorial, it includes [ \t\r\n\f]. That is: \s
>   matches a space, a tab, a line break, or a form feed. Most flavors
>   also include the vertical tab, with Perl (prior to version 5.18) and
>   PCRE (prior to version 8.34) being notable exceptions. In flavors that
>   support Unicode, \s normally includes all characters from the Unicode
>   "separator" category. Java and PCRE are exceptions once again. But
>   JavaScript does match all Unicode whitespace with \s.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

The `@` is a delimiter. Just know that they in `PHP` you always have to put your regex expression inside them. The delimiter can be a `@` or `/` or `#`, ...

Comment: @JAL i hope that it's enough. Maybe the OP will even up-vote it or accept it as the solution, when he will figure out how the features work here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regx

```
 \s\w+:(|\"|\')\w+\1\s?
```

Such as here

```
preg_replace( '/\s\w+:(|\"|\')\w+\1/', '', 'I like to ride a camel tag:videos tag:nope country:"none"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to modify a regex but **I would love if a person could improve it!**

[`/(tag:)"?((?(?<=")[^"]*"|\w*))/i`](https://regex101.com/r/bX5nT3/1)

To completely strip all sorts key:value or key:"value"

[`(\w+:)"?((?(?<=")[^"]*"|\w*))`](https://regex101.com/r/eW0qL0/1)

Doesn't remove whitespaces unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*\S+:(["'])?.*?(?:\1|\s|$)
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/1